# $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$. show that $\{f_n\}$ converges to some function $f$ uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

For $n=1,2,3,...$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, define $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$. show that $\{f_n\}$ converges to some function $f$ uniformly.

**Proof:** In order to determine what $f$ is, we let $n\rightarrow\infty$, then we have $f=0$.

**(Please help me check if these steps are correct):** Since $f=0$, $|f_n|=|f_n-f|$. Therefore, we can use the property of first derivative to find the **maximum or minimum** $f_n$, i.e.$||f_n||$. After taking the first derivative of $f_n$, we have that the maximum value occurs at $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$. So the value of $f_n(\frac{1}{\sqrt n})$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}$. At here, we know that as long as at those extreme points we have are less than $\epsilon$ distance then every other points would certainly be less than $\epsilon$.

Thus, for all $\epsilon>0$, and choose some $N>(\frac{1}{2\epsilon})^2$. Then $\forall n\geq N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, this is one possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$f_n $ is an odd function.

for $x\ge 0$, put

$$g_n (x)=|f_n (x)-0|=\frac {x}{1+nx^2} $$

$$g_n'(x)=\frac {1-nx^2}{(1+nx^2)^2}$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}g_n(\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}})=0$$

Comment: Thank you but that's the same thing~ For this post, I just wanted to double check with the details (the second paragraph under proof.)